# Watchkit`s WKInterfaceImage setImage causes "Terminated due to Memory error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I want to animate images on a watch (like the activity app, if you´re interested, but it´s not important for this problem)

I draw images in a loop first: `GlanceController.m`

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     

for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        // ...

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);

        // ... 

        // create UIImage and save it to an array for later
        UIImage *ejCircle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        [images addObject: ejCircle];
        ejCircle = nil;


        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

So far everything works fine, thanks to autoreleasepool, the memory consumption is not too high here, (about 5 mB before autoreleasepool gets drained back to 2 mB)

However now I try to animate this in a `WKInterfaceImage`, I get a Memory Error:

```
// take the array and create an animated image out of it
UIImage * img = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:images duration:1.0]; 
// memory about normal 2 mB after this line
[wkInterfaceImage setImage:img]; // APP CRASHES HERE
// memory consumption jumps to 30 mB after this line: too much
// for the watch app, the app gets terminated.
[wkInterfaceImage startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,50) duration: 1.0 repeatCount: 1];
```

My question is, **why the app crashes in this line**. The memory consumption explodes, but I don´t `alloc/malloc/new` something here.

### Edit

I just found this crash log in XCode Devices:

```
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Identifier:            MyApp WatchKit Extension
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Version:             ???
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Parent Process:      debugserver [620]
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Date/Time:           2015-07-14 16:04:04.134 +0200
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Launch Time:         2015-07-14 16:03:42.401 +0200
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Report Version:      105
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_RESOURCE
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Exception Subtype: MEMORY
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Exception Message: (Limit 30 MB) Crossed High Water Mark
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Triggered by Thread:  0
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Jul 14 16:04:04 iPhone-6-Plus ReportCrash[622] <Error>: Thread 0 Attributed:
```

Comment: Still having this issue seven years later :(